# Transitioning makefile from Visual Studio + ifort to gfortran?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I need to use some Fortran code that was developed by a co-worker using Microsoft Visual Studio (it is a modified version of [this groundwater flow model](https://water.usgs.gov/nrp/gwsoftware/sutra/sutra.html)). However, I don't have an ifort license, and generally prefer to use open-source alternatives, so I am trying to transition to gfortran. After much googling and time on StackOverflow, I've successfully created a makefile, compiled the code, and run a simulation using gfortran. However, while benchmarking I found that the code I compiled with gfortran runs ~2.5x slower than my coworker's code compiled from Visual Studio (~30 seconds compared to ~13 seconds). Also, the size of the resulting .exe file from gfortran is about half that of Visual Studio.

I understand that there can be some differences in speed just due to switching compilers; however, the difference I observe seems extreme, leading me to believe there are certain compiler settings that differ between the two. **I realize that the question, 'how can I optimize my Fortran code?' is vague and has been answered in detail elsewhere. Instead, my question is: What's the most efficient way to duplicate or approximate a compilation carried out using Microsoft Visual Studio (+ ifort) with gfortran?**

My first instinct was to have my co-worker export a makefile from Microsoft Visual Studio (as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233950(v=vs.60).aspx)), which I could then modify to work with gfortran by using equivalent settings where possible; however, it appears to be no longer possible to export a makefile from within Visual Studio. Second, I looked for a Fortran equivalent to [MakeItSo](https://code.google.com/archive/p/make-it-so/), but didn't have any luck. I also had my co-worker send me screenshots of the Configuration Properties for Fortran in Visual Studio; however, there appear to be Visual Studio settings for which I cannot find clear analogs in gfortran (for example, the "Favor Size or Speed?" switch) seen here:
[image: Visual Studio Settings]

FWIW, I am running gfortran on Cygwin:

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

After help in the comments section from @VladimirF, I have updated my makefile and can confirm that flags are being successfully passed to gfortran:

```
    $ make SUTRA
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o slake_mods.o slake_mods.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o fmods_3_0.o fmods_3_0.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o slake.o slake.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o slake_blas.o slake_blas.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o slake_linpack.o slake_linpack.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o slake_slatec.o slake_slatec.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o ssubs_3_0.o ssubs_3_0.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o usubs_3_0_non-Jeff.o usubs_3_0_non-Jeff.F
    gfortran -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -c -o sutra_3_0.o sutra_3_0.F
    gfortran slake_mods.o fmods_3_0.o slake.o slake_blas.o slake_linpack.o slake_slatec.o ssubs_3_0.o usubs_3_0_non-Jeff.o sutra_3_0.o  -m64  \
    -O3 -march=native -ffixed-line-length-72 -m64 -o SUTRA
```

My co-worker is using Intel Visual Fortran Compiler XE 12.0.2.154 on IA-32 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: The compilers quite differ in some detailed optimization flags, you should not ask how to duplicate those, but how to best optimize your code. Yo should first make sure you are optimizing at all. You should be using at least `-O2` or maybe better `-O3`. And then you can try experimenting with some detailed flags.

Comment: Gfortran equivalent of favor speed might begin with -O3 -march=native.  The default is full debug.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF and @tim18 - I updated the post with more information about the flags I'm currently using, which include `-O3`. I also gave `-march=native` a shot. As a side question, is there a way to test whether I implemented the flags correctly (AKA the model actually compiled in `O3` mode, rather than `debug`?

Comment: You should be able to see the actual commands that are executed. What is the output of you `make` command or the equivalent?

Comment: @VladimirF, I have now added that to the post as well.

Comment: So the answer is no, your flags are not seen by the compiler. We will have to see the Makefile.

Comment: @VladimirF, I have now added those to the post. They were both made by me tweaking some makefiles someone else made for a different program until it compiled - so, may not be well-suited to my current situation.

Comment: Please put here the Makefile as text. If there are too meany repeating lines, you can omit some. If there is no space you can probably remove some details about the Intel and Visual Studio and rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: Updated accordingly

Comment: @VladimirF, FYI: I have successfully fixed the makefile so that flags are being implemented correctly. Using the -O3 flag speeds the run by ~2x, but the gfortran-compiled exe is still ~2.5x slower than the ifort-compiled exe.

Comment: It can happen. Unfortunately it is not an easy topic. One has to identify the part of the code which is slow and why it is slow. Maybe ifortbis able to vectorize some loop which gfortran does not vectorize, who knows.

Comment: Speed difference - is that from both executables running on the same machine?

Comment: Generally I expect `gfortran` to produce slower executables than `Intel Fortran` (even after intensive experimentation with compiler flags).  2.5 times slower, that's towards the upper end of my expectations.  Is OP's friend with money really compiling custom implementations of `BLAS` and  `Linpack` (as OP is) or is the rich friend actually calling functions supplied in Intel's MKL ?

Comment: @cup - Yes, the files were compiled on different machines but run on the same one.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I'm afraid answering your question is beyond my limited knowledge, and in fact I didn't know I was doing anything custom. Based on the Wikipedia entry for `Linpack`, it sounds like I might be better off trying to switch from `Linpack` to `LAPACK`? And, if my rich friend is using functions in Intel's MKL, I assume those aren't available to me via gfortran? Thanks!

Comment: gfortran can certainly call MKL functions but you'll have to find out about licencing and stuff yourself.  And it wouldn't surprise me to find out that MKL functions run more than twice as fast as home-rolled alternatives.  To go any further than these vague generalisations you really ought to profile your code (both versions).  Which is a whole other question.